# How can I launch multiple instances of firefox on multuple VMs remotely with Selenium/Watir?

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, watir

I am building out our automated testing (using Watir).  I've been given a requirement that we need to run 100 instances of Firefox at once, each one running one test.

We found that there is a limit of 15 firefox instances allowed to be open at once, so I was told to create multiple Virtual Machines so that each one can run 15 instances.

However, I've been unable to successfully launch firefox remotely.  Sending the command

```
ssh 123.45.6.789 -pw myPassword
```

tells me that it cannot access Firefox.

Sending the command

```
ssh -X 123.45.6.789 -pw myPassword
```

will launch firefox, but it will do it on the VM that I'm launching from, getting me right back to the issue of the 15-instance limit.

I've done a lot of searching and have been unable to find anything suggesting an effective way to do this.  Can anyone provide help?

Thanks in advance!

Edit to add: I'm not launching firefox itself on the command line.  I'm launching it through Watir like this:

```
Thread.current["tBrowser"] = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
```

Comment: Do you need to have the GUI in order to run these concurrent tests? Have you had any luck with phantomjs?